# I need the difference of (max and min) >40

Tags: sql

I've worked on this query to select min and max from the naap table. I had to group by city and then order by city. Afterward, I am to find the difference between both the max and min > 40

The data and query are below.

However, I need to find the difference between max and min.

***My goal is to show only the results where the difference between max and min is greater than 40.***
How do I find the difference of (max and min) >40
at this point I am lost. Please help?

```
SELECT state, 
    MIN(avg_score),
    MAX(avg_score)
FROM naap
GROUP BY city
HAVING MIN (avg_score) >40
ORDER by city;
```

This is my data

````
columns: avg_score, avg_loss, avg_loss_2, id, city, state, year
table: city_stats
columns: city, average, min_pop, max_pop, standard_deviation```
````

Comment: Just add another column to your "select": `max(avg_score) - min(avg_score) as diff`

Comment: Please tag the database you are using

Comment: Your query is malformed because you are selecting `state` but aggregating by `city`.  I assume the reference should be to `city` throughout the query.  Or perhaps you want both.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you need an expression in the `having` clause:

```
SELECT city, MIN(avg_score), MAX(avg_score), MAX(avg_score) - MIN(avg_score) as diff
FROM naap
GROUP BY city
HAVING  MAX(avg_score) - MIN(avg_score) > 40
ORDER by city;
```

Note that the `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` should be consistent.  I am guessing you want the value by `city` rather than `state`.

Some databases would allow you to use `diff` in the `HAVING` clause rather than repeating the expression.  And, you don't need to select `diff` to filter by it, but I think it is convenient to have it in the result set.

Comment: yes I meant a consistency for city. Thank you for pointing that out. I missed it originally. 
As to the HAVING clause, I think this is what I am looking for. Im going to test it now. I appreciate your guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Please use below query to find the difference,

```
SELECT state, 
    MIN(avg_score),
    MAX(avg_score)
FROM naap
GROUP BY city
HAVING (MAX(avg_score) - MIN(avg_score)) >40
ORDER by city;
```

Comment: Hi Jim, I added the data to the question op. 
My goal is to show the results where the difference between max and min is greater than 40. Not strictly the difference between min and max. I clarified my question above. Thank you!

Comment: Then you just need to provide the function in `HAVING` clause. Provided you the solution, please check